# Best laptop under $800 for Linux gaming?

Tags: laptop, gaming, linux

What's the best laptop under $800 for Linux gaming? I'll use it for Minecraft and general computer stuff. I'll install Linux Mint as the operating system.

Requirements:

- 1920x1080 display (or higher)
- At least 256GB SSD/HDD
- GPU drivers work well with Linux

Best means highest FPS in Minecraft.

Comment: Edited the question. Best means highest FPS in Minecraft.

Comment: Are you planning to play Minecraft or some newer games too? Also, are you willing to wait a few weeks? Some Ryzen 4000 were already released but it's just the first days.

Comment: I'll just be playing Minecraft. No newer games. I've got to get it in the next week or so.

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic also explicitly states _questions asking for general advice about buying hardware are out of scope because they don't necessarily lead to a concrete decision, and go out of date quickly._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest anything with a GTX 1660TI or lower for a GPU. I would assume GTX 1080 or lower will play nicer with Linux due to the GPU's being older and have more robust drivers. Those are going to be cheap, powerful enough for gaming in Minecraft and still leave you with plenty of battery life to use for 7-8 hours if you configure the power usage correctly. (Just be aware that prices are inflated due to the COVID-19 outbreak)

I'd recommend the following:
[Dell G3 15in Gaming Laptop w/ GTX 1050](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/gaming-laptops/dell-g3-15-gaming-laptop/spd/g-series-15-3590-laptop/gnslk5crg302s?view=configurations&configurationid=c6a8572c-c15c-4733-bc75-980867d81c5e)

I have the 2017 version of this laptop (running windows) and I love it. No issues with gaming performance on Minecraft and even more demanding titles like Rainbow Six Siege, BeamNG.Drive, COD: BO4 and Titanfall.